# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes even swapfile is available

Tags: lubuntu, kubuntu, freeze, swap

When I installed lubuntu 18.04 with option "Along side with windows X" it was installed on the unallocated space without swap partition. My system started to freezing randomly so I switched to Kubuntu. unfortunately I installed kubuntu without swap partition. (because at the time of installation I didn't know the swap partition is necessary and lack of swap was actually freezing by lubuntu). Kubuntu started to freezing so I searched on the internet and found the reason. so I used the code `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=0` to turn off swappiness and kubuntu stopped freezing. Even though I have set the value of swappiness to 0 it sometimes getting the value 60 automatically and system starts to freeze again so I have to set it to 0 again and again. So my first question is how to set this value permanently to 0.
2) to solve this is issue I tried to create a swap partition but in my case the command `sudo swapon --show` returns a swapfile already available with 2GB space.so my next question is, if the swap file is already available then why my ubuntu is still freezing while swappiness=60.

all I want is to stop my system from freezing.
[konsole output on swappiness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtUkr.png)

@heynnema I have added the konsole output of /etc/fstab
[konsole output of /etc/fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLqDq.png)

Comment: Default install now uses a swapfile. Only if you already have a swap partition will it use that swap partition. How much RAM do you have. If over 2GB, freezing not related to swap. My old laptop with 1.5GB would pause & go grey for several seconds when it used swap. I just learned not to load multiple large apps at one time. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? If you can get to terminal when it freezes, check these: `top` to see what is running and `free -m` to see is swap used.

Comment: Do you have a Bay Trail or Cherry Trail CPU from Intel?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `cat /etc/fstab`. I'll tell you later how to set vm.swappiness permanently. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @oldfred My processor is intel core 2 CPU 6600 2.4 GHz and Physical Memory is 3.4 GB , Intel GMA 950 Graphics. last time I had lubuntu 16.04 on this system for 2 years and it never freezed.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix My processor is intel core 2 CPU 6600 2.4 GHz and Physical Memory is 3.4 GB , Intel GMA 950 Graphics. last time I had lubuntu 16.04 on this system for 2 years and it never freezed.

Comment: When I install Ubuntu, I never trust that auto magic “alongside Windows” option. Always say “something else” and be in charge of creating all the needed partitions. In your case you only needed two. Make your main partition but leave a little space at the end for swap. Even now it’s not too late. Boot into live Ubuntu, open gparted and shrink your root partition, then create a swap area. With only 4GB ram, it’s nearly necessary to create it.

Comment: You show you are not using swap which you would not with 4GB of RAM. But you only show 3.4GB available. Are you running a 32 bit install on 64 bit hardware? I had a Core2 duo 6500 and converted it to 64 bit in 2009 with total new install & restore backup.

Comment: @oldfred I tried to shrink 1 GB space from the ext4 partition from live USB and installed OS with Gparted but did not succeed. my OS is 64-bit but it still uses 3.4 GB RAM may be due to the limitation of the board.

Comment: I believe default swap file is 2GB, and if creating a swap partition, I would suggest using 2GB, but not required to have swap partition. What are you doing when it freezes? Is it always the same application? Have you installed any software from ppa or directly from a .deb that may not be compatible? Can you get to terminal when gui freezes, to see what is running with `top`?

Comment: So now I installed lubuntu with swap partition. There is no problem with default openbox widows manager but when I switched to compiz window manger ( which was my default with my old lubuntu 16.04)  it started to freeze. Maybe my problem is related with graphics or openGL. For now the temporary solution to my problem is to use openbox as default window manger in lubuntu. I hope this problem will be solved in later LTS version. Thanks for your support @oldfred

Comment: @oldfred problem is finally solved. it was a hardware problem. I did a memTest86 on my both RAMs and found one of them producing errors so I removed it and now system has stopped freezing.